# Load row from database by id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two methods where I'm trying to load records from database based on an Id.
These are my methods:

```
private List<Cliente> GetCLienti(int clienteId) //to load Clients from DB 
{
    var tuttiClienti = _db.tboSottoClienti//Not sure if this query works 
              .Where(c => c.Id_cliente == clienteId)
             .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    //var tuttiClienti = _db.tboClienti.ToList();
    return tuttiClienti;  //I need to return LIST
}

private List<SottoCliente> GetSottoCliente(clienteId)
{
    var tuttiSottoClienti = _db.tboSottoClienti.ToList();
    return tuttiSottoClienti;
}
```

And here is the method that shows it in the view:

```
public IActionResult CaricaSottoCliente(int clienteId)
{
    ViewBag.Cliente = GetCLienti();
    ViewBag.SottoCliente = GetSottoCliente();
    return View();
}
```

This is my view:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Cognome</th>
        <th>Azienda</th>
        <th>Cellulare</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (GestioneAtivita.Models.SottoCliente sottoCliente in ViewBag.SottoCliente)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@sottoCliente.Id</td>
            <td>@sottoCliente.Nome</td>
            <td>@sottoCliente.Cognome</td>
            <td>@sottoCliente.Azienda</td>
            <td>@sottoCliente.Cellulare</td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>

<p><b>Cliente List</b></p>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Enrollment No</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (GestioneAtivita.Models.Cliente cliente in ViewBag.Cliente)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@cliente.Nome</td>
            <td>@cliente.Cognome</td>
            <td>@cliente.Nome_azienda</td>
            <td>@cliente.Cellulare</td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

And finally, this is how I pass ID from another View to the Controller:

```
<td>
   @Html.ActionLink("Sotto Clienti", "CaricaSottoCliente", new { clienteId = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-success" })
</td>
```

How can I return a `List` from the `GetCLienti(int clienteId)` method?
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` but you are not `await`ing it. Neither your method is `async` so replace it with `FirstOrDefault()`. But as your method as return type as `List<Cliente>` you should use `.ToList()` like below.

```
private List<Cliente> GetCLienti(int clienteId) //to load Clients from DB 
{
    var tuttiClienti = _db.tboSottoClienti//Not sure if this query works 
              .Where(c => c.Id_cliente == clienteId)
              .ToList();
    //var tuttiClienti = _db.tboClienti.ToList();
    return tuttiClienti;  //I need to return LIST
}
```

You need to pass `clienteId` value to `GetCLienti` it is having parameter.

```
public IActionResult CaricaSottoCliente(int clienteId)
{
    ViewBag.Cliente = GetCLienti(clienteId);
    ViewBag.SottoCliente = GetSottoCliente();
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

Here I load all data from _db.tboClienti

```
private List<Cliente> GetCLienti(int clienteId)
{
    var tuttiClienti = _db.tboClienti
    .Where(c => c.Id == clienteId)
    .ToList();
    return tuttiClienti;
}
```

Then I pass it   like this :

```
 public IActionResult CaricaSottoCliente(int clienteId)
    {
        ViewBag.Cliente = GetCLienti(clienteId);
        ViewBag.SottoCliente = GetSottoCliente(clienteId);
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

.FirstOrDefaultAsync(); will return only one result.
Remove that, or replace it with .ToList() and your code will return a list of items...